Tailwind CSS box shadow not showing up
I have a vite application and I have defined some colors in the tailwind.config.ts. But for some reason, the colors are showing up but not the box shadow.
page.tsx
<button  className="bg-yellow p-3 !shadow-2xl">
    <Sun className="h-4 w-4" />
</button>

tailwind.config.ts:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  prefix: "",
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['"Balsamiq Sans"', 'sans-serif'],
      },
      colors: {
        background: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--background))",
          dark: "hsl(220 29% 15%)",
        },
        foreground: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
          dark: "hsl(33 36% 95%)",
        },
        text: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(240 5% 10%)",
          dark: "hsl(0 0% 100%)",
        },
        primary: "hsl(45 100% 70%)",
        secondary: "hsl(203 71% 63%)",
        tertiary: "hsl(158 74% 58%)",
        accent1: "hsl(268 62% 55%)",
        accent2: "hsl(25 56% 91%)",
        accent3: "hsl(18 70% 51%)",
        white: "hsl(33 36% 95%)",
        black: "hsl(0 0% 0%)",
        yellow: "hsl(45 100% 70%)",
        blue: "hsl(203 71% 63%)",
        green: "hsl(158 74% 58%)",
        "dark-blue": "hsl(220 29% 15%)",
        purple: "hsl(268 62% 55%)",
        "dark-beige": "hsl(25 56% 91%)",
        orange: "hsl(18 70% 51%)",
      },
      borderRadius: {
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: "0" },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: "0" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}

I have tried setting the box shadow in the global.css file but that does not seem to work either. I even tried to define a boxShadow class in the config file but that does not work too.

Try adding the box shadow by style attribute. If that doesn't work, check if any ancestor element has overflow-hidden.
